# CLIPS deffacts and deftemplates for a family

Tags: clips

First time trying CLIPS in the last few days and must admit it's a little overwhelming. I am at this exercise in the Giarratano book:

```
"Convert the following sentences to facts in a deffacts statement. For each group of related facts, define a deftemplate that describes a more general relationship.

The father of John is Tom.

The mother of John is Susan.

The parents of John are Tom and Susan.

Tom is a father.

Susan is a mother.

John is a son.

Tom is a male.

Susan is a female.

John is a male.
```

So I have tried the following:

```
(deftemplate father-of
    (slot father)
    (slot child)
)

(deftemplate mother-of
    (slot mother)
    (slot child)
)

(deftemplate parents-of
    (slot mother)
    (slot father)
    (slot child)
)

(deftemplate male
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate female
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate father
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate mother
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate son
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate male
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate female
    (slot person)
)

(deffacts family
    (father-of (father Tom) (child John))
    (mother-of (mother Susan) (child John))
    (parents-of (mother Susan) (father Tom) (child John))
    (father (person Tom))
    (mother (perosn Susan))
    (son (person John))
    (male (person Tom))
    (female (person Susan))
    (male (person John))
)
```

When loading into CLIPs, it returns

```
CLIPS> (load familyy.clp)
Defining deftemplate: father-of
Defining deftemplate: mother-of
Defining deftemplate: parents-of
Defining deftemplate: male
Defining deftemplate: female
Defining deftemplate: father
Defining deftemplate: mother
Defining deftemplate: son
Defining deffacts: family
TRUE
```

Is this good? Like it works? I have a bunch of this exercises that I want to do, but does TRUE mean that it's done correctly? What does all the "redefining template mean"

Also if you have any places with examples or anything regarding clips, it's highly appreciated, as I noticed CLIPS resources are kind of slim and hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can download CLIPS related material from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/

In addition to the documentation that can be downloaded, you can also view it online here: http://www.clipsrules.net/Documentation.html

From the documentation for the load command:

Loads the constructs stored in the file specified by  into the environment. If the compilations item is being watched (see section 13.2), then an informational message (including the type and name of the construct) will be displayed for each construct loaded. If the compilations item is not being watched, then a character is printed for each construct loaded (“*” for defrule, “$” for deffacts, “%” for deftemplate, “:” for defglobal, “!” for deffunction, “^” for defgeneric, “&” for defmethod, “#” for defclass, “~” for defmessage-handler, “@” for definstances, and “+” for defmodule). This function returns TRUE if the file was successfully loaded, otherwise FALSE is returned.